# Finding items with eBay PHP SDK does not return seller info

Tags: php, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I'm using David Sadler's [PHP eBay SDK](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php) to integrate eBay in a PHP test application. Using the `$service->findItemsByKeywords`, the result does have `itemId`, `title` and `sellingStatus` but not Seller information (`$item-seller`).

```
object(DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types\SearchItem)[43]
  private 'values' (DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType) => 
    array (size=18)
      'itemId' => string '20197XXXXX' (length=12)
      'title' => string 'Harry ...' (length=78)
      'globalId' => string 'EBAY-US' (length=7)
      'primaryCategory' => 
        object(DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types\Category)[46]
          private 'values' (DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType) => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          private 'attachment' (DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType) => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      'galleryURL' => string 'http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/xxxxxxxx/140.jpg' (length=63)
      'viewItemURL' => string 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/Harry...../20197XXXXX' (length=112)
      'paymentMethod' => 
        object(DTS\eBaySDK\Types\RepeatableType)[45]
          private 'data' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          private 'position' => int 0
          private 'class' => string 'DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types\SearchItem' (length=36)
          private 'property' => string 'paymentMethod' (length=13)
          private 'expectedType' => string 'string' (length=6)
      'autoPay' => boolean true
      'postalCode' => string 'ggggg' (length=5)
      'location' => string 'hhhhhhhhhhh,vv,USA' (length=14)
      'country' => string 'US' (length=2)
      'shippingInfo' => 
        object(DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types\ShippingInfo)[47]
          private 'values' (DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType) => 
            array (size=6)
              ...
          private 'attachment' (DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType) => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      'sellingStatus' => 
        object(DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types\SellingStatus)[48]
          private 'values' (DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType) => 
            array (size=4)
              ...
          private 'attachment' (DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType) => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      'listingInfo' => 
        object(DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types\ListingInfo)[52]
          private 'values' (DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType) => 
            array (size=6)
              ...
          private 'attachment' (DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType) => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      'returnsAccepted' => boolean true
      'condition' => 
        object(DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types\Condition)[57]
          private 'values' (DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType) => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          private 'attachment' (DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType) => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      'isMultiVariationListing' => boolean false
      'topRatedListing' => boolean true
  private 'attachment' (DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType) => 
    array (size=2)
      'data' => null
      'mimeType' => null
```

Could this somehow be a specific situation based on the API key used ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to also use the `outputSelector` field. Set it to "SellerInfo" to "Include information about the seller in the response.". Keep in mind that this is a REPEATABLE field, so you would have to use it like this

```
$request->...->outputSelector = ['SellerInfo','StoreInfo',...];
```